# Why does a resize repeat a click event when the window is resized but not on initial page load?

Tags: jquery, window-resize

If I have a click event inside a `$(window).resize()` that can be triggered by multiple elements such as the example below. I have noticed that on load it just gets fired the once as you'd expect, but when the window is resized it gets fired multiple times as there are elements that can trigger it.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="target">Item 1</li>
    <li class="target">Item 1</li>
    <li class="target">Item 1</li>
    <li class="target">Item 1</li>
    <li class="target">Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.target').on("click", function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active') {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

*This appears to fire multiple times if triggered after the window is resized.*

However, if I place the `$(window).width()` conditional inside the click event then it gets fired just the once whether the window is resized or not.

**JQUERY (using the same HTML as above):**

```
$('.target').on("click", function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

*This will fire only once*

I understand the latter event. That makes sense, but not the former. I also understand that it is related to `$(window).resize()` but why given the first scenario does it repeat in this way?

Comment: I repeat you code in playgournd, and second variant is worked: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/qp15oLw9/4/

Comment: @DenisStukalov Yes, both examples should work, but what I would like to know is why the first behaves in the way it does when the window is resized. eg firing five times.

Comment: Noticed that the number of firings matching the number of elements was coincidental (so not five). Question has  been updated accordingly